# Groups with a certain quotient

Tags: group-theory

I am new to this forum. Please what is the simplest way of showing that the group $(C_{p_1} \rtimes C_{p_2})\rtimes C_2$ has a cyclic quotient of size $2p_2$, where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are odd primes?

Comment: Did you check some cases? Say the particular cases  $\;(p_2,\,p_1-1)=1\;$ (for example, with $\;p_1=5\,,\,p_2=7\;,\;\;p_1=13\;,\;\;29\;$ , etc.), then $\;C_{p_1}\rtimes C_{p_2}=C_{p_1}\times C_{p_2}=C_{p_1p_2}\;$

Comment: Is $\rtimes$ the symbol for semi-direct product ?

Comment: Yes, and in fact $C_5 \times D_6$ (where $D_6$ means dihedral of order $6$) is a counterexample.

Comment: @ Jean Marie, yes, it means semi-direct product. Take any homomorphism you want in the definition of semi-direct product as long as it is not the (trivial) one that makes it a direct product.

Comment: Bur semidirect products $G \rtimes H$  are not always uniquely defined. You need to supply a homomorphism $\phi:H \to {\rm Aut}(G)$.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have added the hypothesis that both the semidirect products are non-trivial.

If the quotient by the (characteristic) $C_{p_1}$ is not cyclic then it's dihedral, so an element $t$ of order $2$ centralises no $p_2$ element, and the normaliser of $C_{p_2}$ must be a dihedral group.

If an element of order $t$ centralises $C_{p_1}$ then so do all its conjugates in $N(C_{p_2})$, and as these generate the normaliser we get that $C_{p_2}$ acts trivially on $C_{p_1}$ which you have said you don't allow.

Now $t$ centralises no element of odd order, so is a fixed point free automorphism of $(C_{p_1} \rtimes C_{p_2})$, which would then be abelian, which you don't allow.